# Where can I get the first edition of Minix OS?

Tags: source-code, minix

I want to know where can I get the first edition of Minix OS? I would like to look at the source code of the first edition of Minix OS.

Comment: One of possible solution is tracking down an old version of the red (or blue?) book or PDF about OS design from prentice Hall. I wont sell you my copy. ;)

Comment: I have no idea if this includes the very first edition, but the Minix project page has [several versions of Minix 1 and 2](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=www:download:previousversions) available for download.

Comment: You can find the source code for version 1.1 and later at https://www.minix-vmd.org/source/std/